# Reset CSS for embeddable web app

Tags: html, css

I have an embeddable web app that can be included on any website. I have been searching for a reasonable way to make it so only the css that I include applies to my app. I came across the idea of a CSS reset but it appears to be just adding default css rules to the html tags. Is it possible to do what I need?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

1. Override styles by loading your CSS last. usually, so that i avoid jQuery UI from being overridden with my styles, I load it's CSS last for safety.

2.The order of styles' importance (as far as i remember) are in this order:

```
-browser styles
-stylesheet styles
-inline styles
-!important styles
-user-defined/user-script styles (custom browser fonts and colors).
```

That's why libraries like jQuery apply inline styles (as opposed to addClass methods) because it always overrides the stylesheet styles, no matter the specificity. but you can override them using !important

3.http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2007/07/27/css-specificity-things-you-should-know/
- this is also the reason why jQuery UI stylesheets have very long/specific style declarations. the more specific it is, the harder it is to override. to demonstrate, the following will always be green even if a definition of red comes after it:

Comment: I'm not really concerned about overriding specific css properties, but what if the page has a CSS like:

`h1{
white-space: no-wrap
}`

but I don't want that to apply to my h1's. Is there some sort of catch-all that I can reset all css props to defaults for a given element?

Comment: Say that my entire app is contained in a div with the id MyAppDiv. Is there a way to have no previous css apply to that div?

Comment: You just can override for "default". " reset all css props to defaults for a given element", just override them to default.

Comment: Can you clarify your last comment please?

Comment: I was hoping to avoid that but o well. Thanks!